# How do I remove the related items created through relationship?

Tags: loopbackjs

I have 3 models: ModelA, ModelB and ModelC.

The model "A" has a relationship (HasManyThrough) with the model "B" through model "C".

How do I remove the related items?

```
module.exports = function(ModelA) {
    ModelA.beforeRemote('deleteById', function(context, remoteMethodOutput, next) {

        //Remove relationships

        next();
    });
};
```

Comment: You want to remove the related items first? is that your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the consideration:

1. Debug context to actually find where is id sent with the request. I used generic example to fetch id of the modelA.
2. To delete related modelB instances, modelAInstance.modelB.destroyAll() where modelB is the name of the relationship, "modelA hasMany modelB".

   ```
    ModelA.beforeRemote('deleteById', function(context, remoteMethodOutput, next) {

        //get the id of ModelA from context object.
        var id = context.req.id;

        //find the model instance to delete.
        ModelA.findById(id, function(err, modelAInstance) {
            if (err) throw err;

            //destroy all ModelB instance related to modelAInstance.
            modelAInstance.modelB.destroyAll({}, function(err, info) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(info);
            });
        });
        next();
    });
   ```